# Remove selected attribute if another select is changed, with Bootstrap Select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to remove the `selected` attribute from a `select` if its sibling `select` changes its `option`. With ordinary jQuery, this code is working as usual. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hv0x43em/1/

However, I'm also using [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

With Bootstrap Select, the `selected` attribute doesn't seem to get removed. Here is my fiddle and code: https://jsfiddle.net/L71xtwx3/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".charts-city").on('change', function(e) {
    var dataOptions = $(this).closest(".form-group").next().find(".charts-data option");
    $(dataOptions).prop("selected", false);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Any idea how to work on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your jsfiddle  demo code you are taking wrong class charts-provinsi instead of charts-city.

here is the working code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".charts-city").on('change', function(e) {
        $(".charts-data").val('0');
        $(".charts-data").selectpicker("refresh");
    });
});
```

here is the referral link
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh

here is the working demo  https://jsfiddle.net/L71xtwx3/6/

Comment: I've edited the fiddle in my question, still didn't work. But you solved it -
 so turns out it's not `deselectAll` or `render`, but `refresh`! I missed that. Thanks!